# How do I automatically have Javascript-animations (with CSS) open in a certain order?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to create an animated envelope on my site.
Right now, the code I'm trying to use only starts the next step of the animation on click.
My question would be how I get the animations to occur automatically after a certain amount of time.

This is how the code looks right now:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Wait for page to load
    window.onload=function(){

$(document).ready(function () {
      // Hide the div
      $("#card").hide();
      // Show the div after 5s
      $("#card").delay(5000).fadeIn(100);  
  });   
        // Add Flip Envelope Event Handler
        document.getElementById('envelope_front').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('envelope_front').classList.toggle('flipped');
            document.getElementById('envelope_back').classList.toggle('flipped');

        }

        // Add Open Envelope Event Handler
        document.getElementById('flap_outside').onclick = function(){

            document.getElementById('flap_outside').classList.toggle('open');
            document.getElementById('flap_inside').classList.toggle('open');

            // Add Remove Card Event Handler
            // This is added after "Open Envelope" so that card can't be removed
            // until the envelope has been opened
            document.getElementById('envelope_back_outside').onclick = function(){
                document.getElementById('card').classList.toggle('removed');
                return false;
            }

            return false;
        }

        // Open Card
        document.getElementById('card').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('card_outside_front').classList.toggle('open');
            document.getElementById('card_inside_top').classList.toggle('open');
            return false;
        }

    }

</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

    body{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #666;
        font-family: Futura, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    }

    #envelope{
        position: relative;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        margin: 200px auto 0 auto;
    }

    #envelope_front{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        z-index: 1; /* This seems required for Chrome */
        background: #FFF url('images/card-sprite.png') 0px 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(10px);
    }

    #envelope_front.flipped{
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }

    #envelope_back{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        background: #FFF url('images/card-sprite.png') -600px -400px;
        -webkit-transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(3px);
    }

    #envelope_back.flipped{
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    #flap_outside{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 600px;
        height: 200px;
        background: transparent url('images/card-sprite.png') -600px -200px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(3px);
    }

    #flap_outside.open{
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(0);
    }

    #flap_inside{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 600px;
        height: 200px;
        background: transparent url('images/card-sprite.png') -600px 0px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateY(-200px) translateZ(3px);
    }

    #flap_inside.open{
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(-200px) translateZ(0);
    }

    #envelope_back_outside{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: transparent url('images/card-sprite.png') 0px -400px;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(2px);
    }

    #card{
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 580px;
        height: 380px;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);
    }

    #card.removed{
        -webkit-animation-name: remove-card;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
        -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    #card_outside_front{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #FFF url('images/card-sprite.png') -1800px 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px);
    }

    #card_outside_front.open{
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }

    #card_inside_top{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        background: #FFF url('images/card-sprite.png') -1210px -10px;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 380px;
        /* 379 is used instead of 380 to prevent any gap between the two layers (visible in Safari) */
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) translateY(-379px) rotateX(-180deg);
    }

    #card_inside_top.open{
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) translateY(-379px) rotateX(0deg);
    }

    #card_inside_bottom{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1; /* Hide behind #card_outside_front and #card_inside_top */
        background: #FFF url('images/card-sprite.png') -1210px 390px;
    }

    /* Animation Keyframes for removing the card */
    @-webkit-keyframes remove-card {

        0% {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) translateZ(1px);
        }

        33% {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-400px) translateZ(1px);
        }

        67% {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-400px) translateZ(3px);
        }

        100% {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) translateZ(3px);
        }

    }
</style>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) with a given `x` delay time:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
   //put your animation code here
 }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To delay the animations in JS (and JQuery) you can use the `delay` function, you already are using it in some places. If you want the delay on the CSS you should apply the `animation-delay` property

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) or you can use css [animation-delay](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp) property without using too much javascript (I usually pick the second).